# apollo client cache updates but ui does not

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

My app makes a deep query for retrieving an object `path` by id and passes down the results through various react props.
Among many other things, a `path` has a list of `steps`. A mutation can add an additional `step` to the `path.steps` list.

I am doing the mutation and then updating the cache afterwards. I can check the InMemoryCache cache afterwards and can see that the item was indeed added. I get no warnings. This is what the relevant piece looks like

```
const { steps } = cache.readFragment({
  id: `Path:${pathId}`,
  fragment: PathLogFragment,
  fragmentName: 'PathLogFragment'
})
cache.writeFragment({
  id: `Path:${pathId}`,
  fragment: PathLogFragment,
  fragmentName: 'PathLogFragment',
  data: { __typename: 'Path', steps: [...steps, addStep] }
})
```

Now I have one component that consumes steps and doesn't update.
It's a pretty simple one, with `steps.map(s => <li>step</li>)`.
It's called like this: `{path.steps && <Steps steps={path.steps} />}`

There are render-props involved in getting the `path` and moving it on, and there are PureComponents on the way, but no `shouldComponentUpdate` calls.

I'm at a loss. What else can I check?

Comment: can you please show how you are rendering your component.

Comment: If you're using `readFragment` to provide the query data to your component, your component won't update when the cache changes because it's designed as a one-time read-access method and does not create an observable query. Please see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349323/6024220

Comment: Thanks! Great info. What's still not plausible to me is that I do have a `<Query/>` associated with the root query that includes the full selection set, including all props in question that do not update. So, by extension of your other answer that queries (even if not polling) are reactive to cache updates, why is my root query not reactively updating the props after the writeFragment change, and giving my downstream component updates?

Comment: `writeFragment` only updates that particular key in the cache, while not updating any of the queries that actually generated it. Since the query your `Query` component uses is untouched, it doesn't trigger an update to any observers subscribing to it. The docs specifically outline using `writeQuery`, not `writeFragment` when updating the cache after a mutation.

Comment: Of course... thanks, would accept an answer, that is very helpful.

Comment: @DanielRearden that's not true. "writeFragment: All subscribers to the Apollo Client cache (including all active queries) see this change and update your application's UI accordingly." See: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/