# How to get updated data from apollo cache

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Does Apollo client have some sort of thing like `mapStateToProps` (Redux)?

let's say I have a component, after query I know there's data in the cache so I do something like:

```
    class Container extends React.Component {
      ...
      ...
      render() {
        const notes = this.props.client.readFragment(NOTES_FRAGMENT)
        // notes has everything I need
        return (<Child notes={notes} />);
      }

    }
    export default WithApollo(Container);
```

However when I have a sibling component which calls mutation and do update, the `<Child />` component's props never get updates.

```
class AnotherContainer extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return(
       <Mutation
          mutation={UPDATE_NOTE}
          update={(cache, {data: {updateNote}}) =? {
            const list = cache.readFragment({
              fragment: NOTES_FRAGMENT
            })
            // manipulate list
            cache.writeFragment({fragment:NOTES_FRAGMENT, data })
          }
        }
     )
   }
}
```

so my question is, how do I update the `<Child />` component's props whenever I do writeFragment? is there anything like mapStateToProps thing to "connect" the `notes` props to the cache, so whenever it updates, will trigger the React lifecycle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`react-apollo` provides three ways you can listen for changes in the cache: 1) the [Query component](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#basic), 2) the [graphql HOC](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql), and 3) calling `watchQuery` directly using the client. In all three cases, you provide some query and any appropriate options, and you get a way to initially fetch that query as well as listen to updates to it.

The key here is that **queries**, and not **fragments** are the intended vehicles for reading the cache. The `readFragment` method is only meant as a convenient way to read the cache a single time (usually in the context of changing the cache after a mutation) and does not provide any sort of reactivity.

So, bottom line, wrap your components in either the `Query` component or the `graphql` HOC and you will have access to props that reflect the query results in the cache and that will update when the cache updates (the same way `connect`ed components do).

At this point a couple of things might be going through your head:

**"But I don't need to make another server request!"** No worries -- by default, Apollo will only request the same query once, and will use the cache for all subsequent calls. You can modify this behavior by setting the appropriate [fetch policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy) for your query. This includes a `cache-only` policy that will only pull data from cache (although the default `cache-first` policy is sufficient for most use cases).

**"But I don't have a query to work with!"** If you're writing to the cache as a means of persisting some arbitrary client-side state, then you should be using [apollo-link-state](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state) to do so.

**"But I don't need the entire query result, just a part of it!"** The `graphql` HOC provides a `props` function you can pass in to the configuration that will let you transform your query data into whatever shape you want to work with. The same functionality isn't really needed when using the render props pattern with the `Query` component -- you can just manipulate the render props directly. In either case, it may be a good idea to write some reducers that you can reuse throughout your project that just take the returned data and transform it into the shape you need. The last big project I worked on did just that client side and it kept things much more manageable.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out many of my doubts of graphql. and yeah I'm actually using query component in other places and works, but for small piece of data, so there is not a a similar like `Fragment` version of Query component right?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, only queries are observable so a fragment equivalent of the `Query` component isn't really feasible right now