# How to handle cache update after mutation in multiple views?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

This is more of a open question but hopefully it won’t get deleted.

I am using react and apollo although the question is more general.

Let’s say I have 3 distinct views in my app all using similar (but not the same) data.
All of them are using separate queries but each of the query uses common operation but with slightly different data returned.

Let’s say I have a mutation somewhere that adds something to data (think of a list of items and a new item being added).

Let’s say after mutation I want to update cache to reflect that change. I am using read/writeQuery to do the update.
With this setup I need to update 3 queries - this becomes a maintenance nightmare.

After some reading I figured I am doing this wrong - I have now created a single query - now I need to only update that single query after mutation and all of my views are updated automatically.
However the problem is that this query now has to download all the data that all 3 views combined need - feels like this is very inefficient, because some of the views will get data they'll never use.

Is there a better way to do it?

Please note that `read/writeFragment` won't work because they won't update the underlying queries - check this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349323/2874705

Please let me know in comment if you need a more concrete example.

All in all I think in this setup I would just be better with a global state handling and avoid apollo cache all together - however I feel cheated cause apollo promised to solve the state problems :)

EDIT

Here's a concerete example:

Let's say our graphql schema is defined liked this:

```
type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    body: String
    published: Boolean!

}

type Query {
    posts(published: Boolean): [Post!]!
}


type Mutation {
  createDraft(body: String!, title: String!): Post
  publish(id: Int!): Post
}
```

Now, we create 3 queries and 2 mutations on the client

```
query PostTitles {
    posts {
        id
        title
    }
}

query Posts {
    posts {
        id
        title
        body
        published
    }
}

query PublishedPosts {
    posts (published: true) {
        id
        title
        body
        published
    }
}

mutation CreateDraftPost ($body: String!, $title: String!) {
    createDraft(body: $body, title: $title) {
        id
        title
        body
        published
    }
}

mutation PublishPost ($id:ID!) {
    publish (id: $id) {
        id
        published
    }
}
```

Just to note `createDraft` creates a post with the default `false` `published` value.

How can use either of those mutations to create or publish a post and have all the 3 cached queries to be updated without using `refetchQueries` or manualy updating each of the query?
I think the real problem is that each of those queries are stored separately in the apollo in-memory cache.

Comment: Yes, a minimal reproducible example would help a lot.

Comment: @DanieleRicci I have added an example - let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, here's how it should goes.

---

In the case of `CreateDraftPost` mutation:

1. You call the mutation and also pass an `update` function. In this `update` function, you modify the cache of the root query `posts` by creating a new fragment of `Post` and then add this fragement into `posts`. See this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates
2. Since the `PostTitles` and `Posts` all rely on the root query `posts` (just differ in the queried fields) and the new fragment of `Post` you've just added into `posts` has sufficient fields, your `PostTitles` and `Posts` should automatically reflect the changes.
3. Since `CreateDraftPost` always create a draft with `published` defaults to `false`. You don't need to update anything related to `PublishedPosts` query.

---

In the case of `PublishPost` mutation:

1. You call the mutation and the returned result is a `Post` with updated fields (`id`, `published`). By the mechanism of Apollo GraphQL cache, this `Post` (identified by `id`) will be updated in any queries it has involved. See this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-a-single-existing-entity
2. However, you need to manually update the `PublishedPost` query. Do this by providing `update` function in the mutation call. In this `update` function, you will `readQuery` of `PublishedPost` first, create a new `Post` out of the returned data and finally `writeQuery` to add this post into the `PublishedPost` results. Reference this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#combining-reads-and-writes

---

How about using `refetchQueries`:

- In the case of `CreateDraftPost` mutation, refetch only `Posts` query should be sufficient (the `PostTitles` should be updated accordingly) since both `Posts` and `PostTitles` rely on the same root query `posts` and fields in `Posts` has also covered fields in `PostTitles`
- In the case of `PublishPost` mutation, I would prefer refetch the `PublishedPost` query to avoid doing the whole `update` thing (since I'm lazy and I think it will not cost me much to refetch 1 query)

Comment: thank you so much for answering. all in all it feels like I could just use a single query and put all the props there (which is what I am doing right now) OR (and I am considering that) just get rid of apollo completely and use global store

Comment: It took me a while to get to know Apollo GraphQL and how all of its caching mechanism works. However, once you understand, it feels much better. For example, in the case of manually maintain a global redux store, you have to deal with loading/error states, normalizing response (https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr), caching response, invalidate cache, cancelling fetching in case component got unmounted. I think Apollo GraphQL has covered those cases well.

Comment: well, of course you wouldn't use redux on its own, for the fetching you could have another library (there's one added to redux now). 
My experience with apollo is not great to be honest. It has confusing API and is buggy imho  - for example intervals are handled badly, I usually go for useInterval hook; some method return Promises some not; code generation gets silent on syntax errors; not to mention how bad docs are;
I could go on on countless hours I lost working with apollo and I wouldn't recommend it to anyone to be honest

Comment: I understand, it depends on use case too. I hope you're doing good.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've looked into and used the update argument that can be passed to mutation functions returned from useMutation. You're probably using proxy.readQuery and proxy.writeQuery to update it (or letting this magic happen in the background). If not, here is the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation).

Another approach that is similar in concept but finer detail is to use proxy.readFragment and proxy.writeFragment. You can specify a set of properties on a type as being part of a fragment, and update that fragment whenever new data comes in. The nice part is that this fragment can be used within any number of queries, and if you update the fragment, those queries will update.

[fragment documentations](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#writefragment-and-readfragment)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have used read/writeQuery, I should’ve made it clear in the question. However this is problematic for the reasons I explained in the question - you either have to update multiple queries or create single query, both of the solutions seem bad. The problem with writeFragment  is that it’s not observable - it won’t update queries automatically.